# VBA: Using worksheet name and/or range name as inputs to function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple function that shades every other row of a given range in a worksheet:

```
Public Function ShadeEveryOtherRow()
Sheets("mySheet").Select
ShadedRows = Range("myRange").Rows.Count
' determines the number of rows to shade in the range

' Code that loops through and shades rows here

End Function
```

I would like to be able to call this function with a given worksheet name and range as inputs. If I write the function as shown below and attempt to execute using the test() sub, I get a "Compile Error: Type mismatch" error. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Public Function ShadeEveryOtherRow(targetSheet As Worksheet, targetRange As Range)

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range

Sheets(targetSheet).Select
shadeRows = Range(targetRange).Rows.Count

'Code that shades rows here

End Function


Sub test()
ShadeEveryOtherRow "mySheet", "myRange"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetRange` and `targetSheet` should be of type string, instead of being passed to the function as objects.

```
Public Function ShadeEveryOtherRow(targetSheet As string, targetRange As string)

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range

Sheets(targetSheet).Select
shadeRows = Range(targetRange).Rows.Count

'Code that shades rows here

End Function


Sub test()
ShadeEveryOtherRow "mySheet", "myRange"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't `Dim` your variables twice. Declaring them in the function signature is sufficient. Also, don't use `.Select`. Do what you want to do explicitly.

```
Public Function ShadeEveryOtherRow(targetSheet As string, targetRange As string)

shadeRows = Sheets(targetSheet).Range(targetRange).Rows.Count

'Code that shades rows here

End Function
```

Edit:
Like Sigil points out below you should be using strings for your variables. THe other option is to pass in the range explicitly.

```
Public Function ShadeEveryOtherRow(targetRange As Range)

    shadeRows = targetRange.Rows.Count

    'Code that shades rows here
End Function


Sub test()
    ShadeEveryOtherRow Sheets("mySheet").Range("myRange")
End Sub
```

And remember! Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of all your code.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Your suggestion solved the problem, and as a true VBA rookie I appreciate your additional guidance as well.

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, a table would definitely do this faster and easier, you're right. It's much more dynamic too. Who knows what the OP's workflow is though.